# How to build and install dpdk v.18.08 on Centos 7.6 with gcc?

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to build and install dpdk v.18.08 on Centos 7.6 with gcc 4.8.5.

This is what I have done:

```
$ tar xvfz /opt/dpdk/dpdk-18.08/tar.gz
$ cd /opt/dpdk/dpdk-18.08
$ make -j T=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc install
<snip>
Build complete [x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc]
Installation cannot run with T defined and DESTDIR undefined
```

How can I fix this failure to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a specific folder to house current binaries and library, 'make config T=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc O=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc'.

This will create a folder 'x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc'. You have set RTE_TARGET as x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc. Then build by 'cd x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc; make -j 10'

Edit: O in 'make config' is the target folder.